# Real and Complex Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

A projection $P$ on a real vector space is defined to be a linear mapping such that $P^2 = P$. For projections on complex vector spaces why does one require the extra condition that $P^* = P$, where $P*$ is the Hermitian of $P$?

Comment: You don;t mean Hermitian; you mean "adjoint". See also Darsh's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting your concepts confused. $P^2=P$ defines projections in any vector space; the additional constraint $P^*=P$ only makes sense in inner product spaces and defines *orthogonal* projections. (Projections don't have to be orthogonal.)

Comment: Don't you mean unitary if we're talking about complex vector spaces?

Comment: You could be right, but I've only heard the phrase "orthogonal projection," even for complex vector spaces. I've only heard the word "unitary" used in the context of unitary transformations, i. e., ones that satisfy UU\* = U\*U = I. If the word applies here, then I'm happy to edit my answer...

Comment: @John: In the context of inner product spaces and operators on them, unitary almost always means what Darsh has said. At least, this is in my experience. (The word orthogonal is being used in the sense of "mutually orthogonal vector", not in the O(n) sense)

Comment: Over a real vector space, one sometimes requires that P^T=P. These are called the orthogonal projections. This is precisely analogous to requiring that P^*=P in a complex vector space.